# Pandas: replace empty cell to 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `results` that contains empty cells and I would like to replace all empty cells with 0.

So far I have tried using pandas' `fillna`:

```
result.fillna(0)
```

and `replace`:

```
result.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)
```

However, both with no success.

Comment: Are you assigning the returned dataframe? E.g. `result = result.fillna(0)`? Otherwise you need to add the argument `inplace=True`

Comment: @Kristof I have an empty cells with it

Comment: Define "empty". Are you sure these are `np.nan`? Perhaps they are `''`?.

Comment: @DeepSpace some values like this `fffee6e502177bb0297b8857dd1d2f7e          NaN       NaN         NaN `

Comment: @Kristof  it replace it in df, but to excel write empty

Comment: Use the ```na_rep=0```  [option](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas-dataframe-to-excel) when you write ```to_excel```

Answer (score 44):

You are creating a copy of the dataframe but the original one is not keeping the changes, you need to specify "inplace=True" if you want the dataframe to persist the changes

```
result.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Mine gives "0.0" instead of "0", any ideas?

Comment: try `result.fillna(0, inplace=True, downcast='infer')` if the rest of the column is an integer. You can always covert it to integer after the fact otherwise

Answer (score 2):

If the empty field means '' (empty sign) then you can use:

```
dataframe['column_name'].replace('',0)
```

That creates a new series with the replaced values, so to update the original dataframe do:

```py
dataframe['column_name'] = dataframe['column_name'].replace('',0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty values replace with zero.

```
df = df.replace('',0)
```

or

```
df = df.replace('',np.nan).fillna(0)
```