# How to input missing values in a date column using Python?

Tags: python

I have two columns order approved date and order delivered date, they have missing values and I am unable to figure out what function or feature could help me fill missing values?

Kindly help me here[image: missing value screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: replace empty cell to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569851/pandas-replace-empty-cell-to-0)

Comment: is that a pandas.DataFrame ? With what value do you want to fill the empty ?

Comment: If those orders haven't been approved or their delivery timestamp isn't recorded, it sounds like a terrible idea to just come up with some arbitrary replacement value.

Comment: For numerical we could impute using median/mean and likewise for categorical with mode but how about for date columns is my question

Comment: I could use the same dates for order approved as of order purchased but quite not sure about order delivered dates.

Comment: *input. Also, that is a very bad idea if you are actually using this. The solution is to find why there is missing data.

Comment: @OctopuSS7- What if I take average time to deliver a product and fill the null values with the same?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change missing values with "0", it may works >>>

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = #your data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.fillna(0)
```

But want to change them column by column, may be you should use >>>

```
data["column x"].fillna("No Date or Related Date", inplace = True)
```