# How to replace the blank cells in Excel with 0 using Python?

Tags: python, excel, loops

I'm trying to replace the blank cells in excel to 0 using Python. I have a loop script that will check 2 excel files with the same WorkSheet, Column Headers and Values. Now, from the picture attached,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzJtT.png)

the script will write the count to Column Count in Excel 2 if the value of Column A in Excel 2 matches to the value of Column A in Excel 1. Now, the problem that I have are the values in Column A in Excel 2 that doesn't have a match in Column A in Excel 1, it leaves the Column Count in Excel 2 blank.

Below is a part of the script that will check the 2 excel files I have. I'm trying the suggestion from this link [Pandas: replace empty cell to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569851/pandas-replace-empty-cell-to-0) but it doesn't work for me and I get result.fillna(0, inplace=True) NameError: name 'result' is not defined error message. Guidance on how to achieve my goal would be very nice. Thank you in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import openpyxl

daily_data = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Test.xlsx')
master_data = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Source.xlsx')

daily_sheet = daily_data['WorkSheet']
master_sheet = master_data['WorkSheet']

for i in daily_sheet.iter_rows():
    Column_A = i[0].value
    row_number = i[0].row
    for j in master_sheet.iter_rows():
        if j[0].value == Column_A:
            daily_sheet.cell(row=row_number, column=6).value = j[1].value
            
            #print(j[1].value)

daily_data.save('C:/Test.xlsx')
daily_data = pd.read_excel('C:/Test.xlsx')
daily_data.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Where did `result` come from?  I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: @TimRoberts actually, from my original script, the result is not there but i'm trying the suggestion from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569851/pandas-replace-empty-cell-to-0 that's why I included that in my question. Unfortunately, I cannot make it work. Any suggestion please? Thank you.

Comment: Well, `fillna` may be the thing you need, but don't you think you should be running that on the sheet you want to change?

Comment: @TimRoberts I see and I agree that it should run on the sheet that I want to change. But how can I fill the values in Excel 2 with blank to 0 without filling all the other blank cells without value? Sorry still new in Python but I am learning a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you've made a few fundamental mistakes in your approach. First off, "result" is an object, specifically its a dataframe that someone else made (from that other post) *it is not your dataframe.* Thus, you need to run it on *your dataframe.* In python, we have whats called an object oriented approach, meaning that objects are the key players. .fillna() is a mthod that operates on your object. Thus the usage for a toy example is as follows:

```
my_df = pd.read_csv(my_path_to_my_df_)
my_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

also this method is for dataframes thus you will need to convert it from the object the openpyxl library creates, at least thats what i would assume i haven't used this library before. Therefore in your data you would do this:

```
daily_data = pd.read_excel('C:/Test.xlsx')
daily_data.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: thank you for your inputs and I have learned a lot. I will try this and give you feedback. Again, thank you!

Comment: I inserted this code after daily_data.save('C:/Test.xlsx') but nothing happen. It didn't replace the blank cells with 0 on column Count of Excel 2. Doesn't have errors as well. Any idea what I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: how are you determining this? Are you viewing it through an IDE or through the saved excel sheet, because if its the latter thats because if the code is inserted after the line you used to save the modified dataframe, you are saving it before applying the fillna method

Comment: I'm viewing it through the saved excel sheet. Also, I tried inserting the code before saving the dataframe and here is what I get. return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'save'. Did you mean: 'shape'?

Comment: daily_data.save (where save as an attribute) doesn't work anymore.

Comment: This is because you are confusing the functionality of two libraries. Pandas does not have a save method, that is openxlpy. You can't apply methods from one object to another object. If you need to save the file use pandas .to_csv() method

Comment: I see. However, the file is xlsx and I don't want it to convert to .csv.

Comment: you can just put .xlsx into the filename. it will save properly.

Comment: you can also use .to_excel()

Comment: Thanks rsenne but could you suggest the syntax please? I am trying to find the correct solution as well.

Comment: I've given a lot of help already, I'm happy to help with syntax if you edit your answer to show me what you've attempted.

Comment: hi @rsenne, I updated the question field with the code but it doesn't replace the blank cells to 0. thank you very much for your help